# Make hidden required field visible if not filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, required

I am using JQuery UI's [tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation) coupled with a form to allow a user to submit data to a php function. Each tab the user creates is essentially another run of this function, just with the different parameters specified by that tab. Having this be the case, I have certain fields in these tabs marked as `required` in HTML, as they are necessary for the backend function to run. The HTML validation of these fields is fine if the faulty tab is selected, but an error is thrown if the faulty tab is not selected:

```
An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable.
```

Where name is set to the incomplete field's name attribute. This makes sense to me since the not shown tabs have there visibility set to `false`, so the browser thinks the field is not possible to focus on to show the user they need to fill it in.

My question is, is there a way to *intercept* this name attribute, or the field itself, that is causing the invalidation before the error is thrown? Ideally I would like to get a reference to the element, which would allow me to select the invalid tab for the user, thus allowing proper validation protocols to occur.

I have looked around for how to handle required hidden fields and it seems like the general consensus is to remove the `required` attribute of all hidden fields on form submit. While this would fix the error, I cannot do this since the fields are necessary for backend functions after submission. While doing a backend check of which tabs are complete and running the function only on those tabs is possible, it would be undesirable since the user is expecting all tabs' data to run on submission, not just some.

An abbreviated set up for the form and tabs is below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $( function() { 
                var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
            } );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='form'>
            <div id="tabs">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab Two</a></li>
                  </ul>
                <div id="tabs-1">
                    <input type='text' name='some_field_1' value='User entered text...' required />
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-2">
                    <input type='text' name='some_field_2' required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Submitting this would make the error above read:

```
An invalid form control with name='some_field_2' is not focusable.
```

Since `some_field_2` has not been filled in and is not visible on selection. Each field's name does have a number as shown set on tab creation with JQuery that is indicative of the tab it falls under, so the general name form is `some_field_#`. You can assume there to be any number of tabs and any one or many of them may be invalid on submit.

Comment: `Make hidden required field visible if not filled` how can you fill up an input that is hidden?

Comment: @guradio Was I not clear in the question? If you select a tab the fields under that tab become visible, thus allowing you to fill in those fields.

Comment: Does your form wrap all the tabs? Not clear what exact layout is. Will probably have to checkValidity yourself and find out if that tab is hidden or not. Best suggestion though is validate each tab `<fieldset>` before allowing user to move to another one. Create a demo in a sandbox site like jsfiddle, plunker, codepen etc

Comment: @charlietfl I edited the question with a runnable example. Clicking `Submit` will cause the error to occur.

Comment: Might want to look at one of the many form wizard scripts around instead of re-inventing the wheel